# $g^{-1}(A) $ is open if $A$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider the function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $g(x) = x^2$. Show that for all $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ open, $g^{-1}(A)$ is open

**Definition** :$g^{-1}(A) =${$x \in {\rm Dom(g)}: g(x) \in A$}

I've tried to do this using the definition of open set. Using that my set $A$ is open and getting $x \in g^{-1}(A)$ (if this set is not empty), I've tried to find my $\varepsilon$ using that $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $B_{\delta}(g(x)) \subset A$. But I didn't make much progress.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to show this for open intervals and then show that it suffice.

Comment: It is enough to show for open intervals since my open set can be expressed by a union of open intervals

Comment: Did you ever do a proof to show that a function like $x\mapsto x^2$ is continuous?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz No, I didn't, but I can see the relation of continuity and this question

Comment: That's good, see my hint then.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
What does $B_\delta(x)$ boil down to on $\mathbb R$?
What is the preimage of an interval $g^{-1}([a,b])$?

Comment: Did you mean $(a,b)$? I still don't get how to find my $\varepsilon$, sorry.

Comment: Try to go along the two questions, you should come up with something like $g^{-1}(B_{\epsilon}(x))$ is open.

Comment: I think I have to deal with the following cases: $A \subset Im(g)$ and $A \not \subset Im(g)$. Using the intervals notation (since my set can be expressed as a union of open intervals), if $(b,a) \subset [0, \infty)$, then $g^{-1}((b,a)) = (-\sqrt{a}, -\sqrt{b}) \cup (\sqrt{b}, \sqrt{a})$. Else, $g^{-1}((b,a)) = (-\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{a})$ if a is non negative. But I don't see how to prove it without using g is continuous (and this idea is before continuity)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

For $|h|\le 1$ you have
$$|(x+h)^2-x^2|=|2xh+h^2|=|h|\cdot|2x+h|\le|h|(2|x|+1).$$
This should help you to find an $\varepsilon$ corresponding to a given $\delta$.